# PyQt5 Code fails when a certain function starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I created a pyqt script, well the script was already created by myself but i yesterday started learning pyqt and just implemented a function from from my script but it crashes soon after function is called. I am beginner with pyqt so I agree that the format might be poor.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from lxml import html
import requests

class Ui_ShopifyFeeder(object):
    def started(self):
        print("STARTED...\n")
        resp = requests.get('https://www.google.com/', headers=headers)
        print(resp.content)


    def setupUi(self, ShopifyFeeder):
        ShopifyFeeder.setObjectName("ShopifyFeeder")
        ShopifyFeeder.resize(423, 105)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.constant_value = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.constant_value.setEnabled(True)
        self.constant_value.setObjectName("constant_value")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.constant_value, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.percentage_value_selection = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.percentage_value_selection.setObjectName("percentage_value_selection")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.percentage_value_selection, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.percentage_value = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.percentage_value.setObjectName("percentage_value")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.percentage_value, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.constant_value_selection = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.constant_value_selection.setObjectName("constant_value_selection")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.constant_value_selection, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.starter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.starter.clicked.connect(self.started)
        self.starter.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.starter.setObjectName("starter")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.starter)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 3, 0, 1, 2)

        self.retranslateUi(ShopifyFeeder)
        self.starter.clicked['bool'].connect(ShopifyFeeder.setEnabled)
        self.starter.clicked['bool'].connect(self.constant_value.setEnabled)
        self.constant_value_selection.clicked['bool'].connect(self.constant_value.setDisabled)
        self.percentage_value_selection.clicked['bool'].connect(self.percentage_value.setDisabled)
        self.constant_value_selection.clicked['bool'].connect(self.percentage_value_selection.setDisabled)
        self.constant_value_selection.clicked['bool'].connect(self.percentage_value.setDisabled)
        self.percentage_value_selection.clicked['bool'].connect(self.constant_value.setDisabled)
        self.percentage_value_selection.clicked['bool'].connect(self.constant_value_selection.setDisabled)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ShopifyFeeder)

    def retranslateUi(self, ShopifyFeeder):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ShopifyFeeder.setWindowTitle(_translate("ShopifyFeeder", "ShopifyFeeder"))
        self.percentage_value_selection.setText(_translate("ShopifyFeeder", "Percentage"))
        self.constant_value_selection.setText(_translate("ShopifyFeeder", "Constent"))
        self.starter.setText(_translate("ShopifyFeeder", "Start"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ShopifyFeeder = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_ShopifyFeeder()
    ui.setupUi(ShopifyFeeder)
    ShopifyFeeder.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So as soon as started function/method is called, script crashes after print statement. It would be nice if I can have some info about whats wrong.

NOTE: This piece of code works but it opens a link in my browser while i want it to work exactly as requests and basic python scripts.

```
def started(self):
    print("STARTED...\n")
    url = QtCore.QUrl('https://www.yahoo.com/')
    if not QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(url):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Open Url', 'Could not open url')
```

Okay i tried again with this new method and still script crashes.

```
def loadPage(self):
    print("STARTED...\n")
    page = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop() # Create event loop
    page.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(loop.quit) # Connect loadFinished to loop quit
    page.mainFrame().load('https://www.yahoo.com/')
    loop.exec_() # Run event loop, it will end on loadFinished
    print( page.mainFrame().toHtml() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was rather simple problem, the issue was

> .content

I actually had to use

> .text

and after that everything worked out well.

`r.text` is the content of the response in unicode, and `r.content` is the content of the response in bytes. I was using PyQt5 and python 3.5 and latest version of requests.

Here is that def/method:

```
def loadPage(self):
    print("STARTED...\n")

    resp = requests.get('https://www.yahoo.com/')

    tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)
    print("\nFinished...")
```